# Array access and assignment has variable alignment size in LLVM IR output generated by clang

Tags: clang, llvm-ir

Hey I'm working on a project where I'm creating a compiler.
While trying to implement array element assignment I ran into this piece of llvm ir code:

```
define dso_local i32 @main() {
  %1 = alloca [10 x i32], align 16
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %1, i64 0, i64 0
  store i32 2, i32* %2, align 16
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %1, i64 0, i64 1
  store i32 4, i32* %3, align 4
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %1, i64 0, i64 2
  store i32 6, i32* %4, align 8
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %1, i64 0, i64 3
  store i32 8, i32* %5, align 4
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %1, i64 0, i64 4
  store i32 10, i32* %6, align 16
  ret i32 0
}
```

Generated from:

```c
int main () {
    int x[10];
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 4;
    x[2] = 6;
    x[3] = 8;
    x[4] = 10;
}
```

While inspecting the IR output, I noticed that the alignment always seems to be different (16-4-8-4). I am quite puzzled by this, and don't know why the alignment would be variable. Any hints or nudges in the right directions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clang seems to be using its knowledge of the alloca's alignment and the pointer offsets to compute the maximum alignment of each element individually. The alloca is aligned to 16B, so a pointer to element 0 (no offset) will have that alignment. But since the elements in the array in the alloca are only 4B in size (`i32`), which is less than 16B, the pointer alignment changes once you offset it to get later elements.

Clang could just set the alignment on everything here to be 4 instead, but there's no rule that requires it to. Moreover there can be some benefits to using this large alignment of 16 for the array, such as enabling 4 elements (4 × 4B = 16B) to be loaded at once with a SIMD instruction.